# Generate a random point on an elliptical curve

Tags: python-3.x, differential-equations, elliptic-curve

I'm writing a program which randomly chooses two integers within a certain interval. I also wrote a class (which I didn't add below) which uses two numbers 'a' and 'b' and creates an elliptical curve of the form:
y^2 = x^3 + ax + b

I've written the following to create the two random numbers.

```
def numbers():
n = 1
while n>0:
    a = random.randint(-100,100)
    b = random.randint(-100,100)
    if -16 * (4 * a ** 3 + 27 * b ** 2) != 0:
        result = [a,b]
        return result
    n = n+1
```

Now I would like to generate a random point on this elliptical curve. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve has an infinite length, as for every *y ϵ ℝ* there is at least one *x ϵ ℝ* so that *(x, y)* is on the curve. So if we speak of a random point on the curve we cannot hope to have a homogeneous distribution of the random point over the whole curve.

But if that is not important, you could take a random value for *y* within some range, and then calculate the roots of the following function:

*f(x) = x<sup>3</sup> + ax + b - y<sup>2</sup>*

This will result in three roots, of which possibly two are complex (not real numbers). You can take a random real root from that. This will be the *x* coordinate for the random point.

With the help of `numpy`, getting the roots is easy, so this is the function for getting a random point on the curve, given values for *a* and *b*:

```
def randomPoint(a, b):
    y = random.randint(-100,100)
    # Get roots of:  f(x) = x^3 + ax + b - y^2
    roots = numpy.roots([1, 0, a, b - y**2])
    # 3 roots are returned, but ignore potential complex roots
    # At least one will be real
    roots = [val.real for val in roots if val.imag == 0]
    # Choose a random root among those real root(s)
    x = random.choice(roots)
    return [x, y]
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/GQx8/9).

Comment: And what if I need the root to be exact? How do I do this?

Comment: Root values are most often irrational numbers, so they can never have an exact representation in the decimal representation (infinite number of decimals), nor in the floating point representation. You could however round the number to X significant digits.